# angularJS can't add string to an array in $scope function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to get my jaddString into my array but it won't work. The string get's made but it just doesn't go into the array. In my console on google chrome i get this error:
ReferenceError: aa is not defined

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('kompileApp', []).controller('partsList', function($scope){
this.aa = addedArray;
this.aaString = addedArrayString;
this.jaddString = justAdded;

$scope.jadd = function(partId){
        jaddString = parts[partId - 1].id + ': ' + parts[partId - 1].name + ', ' + parts[partId - 1].price;

        aa[partId - 1] = jaddString;
    };
});

[
{
id: 1,
name: 'vitamine A',
price: 3,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: '2, 5'
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'vitamine B',
price: 5,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: '1'
},
{
id: 3,
name: 'vitamine C',
price: 2,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: ''
},
{
id: 4,
name: 'Opium',
price: 20.95,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: ''
},
{
id: 5,
name: 'steroids',
price: 12.5,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: '1'
}
];

var addedArray = new Array(parts.length);

var justAdded = '';
```

in my html i call the function inside the ng-click but it 
html:

```
<div ng-controller="partsList as pl" class="ctrlDiv">
<li ng-repeat="part in pl.parts | orderBy:'+price'" ng-hide="part.added || !part.canAdd" class="plLi">
<button ng-click="jadd(part.id); pl.aa[part.id] = pl.jaddString" ng-show="part.canAdd" class="plistbutton">add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

if i assign a value to my array like this and show it in my html page it does show the value. So i guess it is defined well?:

```
var addedArray = new Array(10);
addedArray[0] = 'lalala'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make somekind of alias for `this` object to make it available in `jadd` function.

Like

```
var app = angular.module('kompileApp', []).controller('partsList', function($scope){
{
   var self = this;
   self.aa = addedArray;
   self.aaString = addedArrayString;
   self.jaddString = justAdded;
   $scope.jadd = function(partId){
      self.jaddString = parts[partId - 1].id + ': ' + parts[partId - 1].name + ', ' + parts[partId - 1].price;
      self.aa[partId - 1] = self.jaddString;
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First : not $scope.jadd but this.jadd and change in the ng-click the jadd call by cl.jadd. It's not a good idea to mix this and $scope.
Furhtermore i don't think that this is implicit in javascript. so you should do this :

```
this.jadd = function(partId){
    this.jaddString = parts[partId - 1].id + ': ' + parts[partId - 1].name + ', ' + parts[partId - 1].price;

    this.aa[partId - 1] = jaddString;
};
```

});